# TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "@open-wc/testing". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../"

Tags: npm, karma-jasmine, web-component

I am trying to find some good way to unit test m y vanilla webcomponents and I am trying this approach [open-wc](https://open-wc.org/testing/#setup) and I am getting error mentioned above

my-component-test.js

```
import {
  html,
  fixture,
  expect,
} from '@open-wc/testing';
import { MyComponent } from "../src/my-component.js";

describe("simple test", () => {
  it("test", async () => {
    const el = await fixture("<my-component></my-component>");
    expect(el.success).to.be.false;
  });
});
```

relevant part from package.json

```
  "scripts": {
    "test": "karma start",
...
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@open-wc/testing": "^1.0.14",
    "@webcomponents/webcomponentsjs": "^2.2.0",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.0.2",
    "es-dev-server": "^1.6.3",
    "eslint": "^6.0.1",
    "eslint-config-google": "^0.13.0",
    "karma": "^4.2.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^3.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "^2.0.1",
    "karma-script-launcher": "^1.0.0",
    "karma-spec-reporter": "0.0.32",
    "prettier": "1.18.2",
    "wct-browser-legacy": "^1.0.2",
    "web-component-tester": "^6.9.2"
  },
```

console

```
# npm test 



> basic-vanilla-webcomponent@ test C:\_d\WSs\basic-vanilla-webcomponent                                                                       
> karma start                                                                                                                                 

16 07 2019 18:57:51.712:INFO [karma-server]: Karma v4.2.0 server started at http://0.0.0.0:9876/                                              
16 07 2019 18:57:51.719:INFO [launcher]: Launching browsers Chrome with concurrency unlimited                                                 
16 07 2019 18:57:51.730:INFO [launcher]: Starting browser Chrome                                                                              
16 07 2019 18:57:54.850:INFO [Chrome 75.0.3770 (Windows 10.0.0)]: Connected on socket Hf1IzCLlm_IaBeZXAAAA with id 12297274                   
Chrome 75.0.3770 (Windows 10.0.0) ERROR                                                                                                       
  An error was thrown in afterAll                                                                                                             
  ReferenceError: require is not defined                                                                                                      
      at node_modules/find-port/test/findPort.test.js:1:16                                                                                    
  ReferenceError: require is not defined                                                                                                      
      at node_modules/registry-auth-token/test/auth-token.test.js:1:10                                                                        
  ReferenceError: require is not defined                                                                                                      
      at node_modules/registry-auth-token/test/registry-url.test.js:1:10                                                                      
  ReferenceError: require is not defined                                                                                                      
      at node_modules/winston/test/transports/00-file-stress.test.js:11:12                                                                    
  ReferenceError: require is not defined                                                                                                      
      at node_modules/winston/test/transports/01-file-maxsize.test.js:8:16                                                                    
  ReferenceError: require is not defined                                                                                                      
      at node_modules/winston/test/transports/console.test.js:11:14                                                                           
  ReferenceError: require is not defined                                                                                                      
      at node_modules/winston/test/transports/file-archive.test.js:10:16                                                                      
  ReferenceError: require is not defined                                                                                                      
      at node_modules/winston/test/transports/file-tailrolling.test.js:2:16                                                                   
  ReferenceError: require is not defined                                                                                                      
      at node_modules/winston/test/transports/file.test.js:3:14                                                                               
  ReferenceError: require is not defined                                                                                                      
      at node_modules/winston/test/transports/http.test.js:7:12                                                                               
  ReferenceError: require is not defined                                                                                                      
      at node_modules/winston/test/transports/stream.test.js:3:14                                                                             
  TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "@open-wc/testing". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../".           

Chrome 75.0.3770 (Windows 10.0.0): Executed 0 of 0 ERROR (0.02 secs / 0 secs)                                                                 

npm ERR! Test failed.  See above for more details.
```

version checked

```
# npm list @open-wc/testing
basic-vanilla-webcomponent@ C:\_d\WSs\basic-vanilla-webcomponent
`-- @open-wc/testing@1.0.14
```

*** edited in 2019 Jully 22

I change the import by writing the whole to path (import { html, fixture, expect } from "C:/_d/WSs/basic-vanilla-webcomponent/node_modules/@open-wc/testing";) and then I got this error that doesn't help much:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was facing the same issue but pointing `tests` inside the `src` folder works without any error. So for example

This gives the same error like yours

```js
{
   pattern: 'test/**/*.test.js',
   type: 'module'
}
```

But this works well

```js
{
   pattern: 'src/**/*.test.js',
   type: 'module'
}
```

Comment: Does this mean I need to move my *.test.js files from test/ into src/ ?

Answer (score 1):

I encountered a similar problem, but my solution was to add the following code in `karma.conf.js`:

```js
esm: {
  nodeResolve: true,
},
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try to add `./` if the `@open-wc` is in the main public folder:

```
import {
  html,
  fixture,
  expect,
} from './@open-wc/testing';
```

Comment: Sorry it doesn't fix or change significantly anything. Just added a warnning 404. Maybe "./" is even worse. Here is the output: ...

17 07 2019 13:17:06.282:INFO [Chrome 75.0.3770 (Windows 10.0.0)]: Connected on socket IH7KBqJyxWHJugO3AAAA with id 93745076
17 07 2019 13:17:06.779:WARN [web-server]: 404: /base/test/@open-wc/testing
Chrome 75.0.3770 (Windows 10.0.0) ERROR
  An error was thrown in afterAll
  ReferenceError: require is not defined

Comment: @JimC it's not worse, it's better: it says that the file is not found at that path. You should set an absolute path or the right relative path (that we cannot guess for you)

Comment: I tried relative path ('../node_modules/@open-wc/testing') but it results in same error. You can see the whole code in https://github.com/jimisdrpc/basic-vanilla-webcomponent/blob/master/test/my-component.test.js. Interesting is that IN Visual Studio Code it finds the folder @open-wc/testing but it is missed when I run the test via npm test.

Comment: why "../" and not "./"? what is the relative path?

Comment: I tried all possibilities without success. If you git clone my project you will see the relative path. BTW, at this moment, I am w0ondering if I am missing some extra configuration karma.conf.js in order to make @open-wc/testing available during my tests. Kindly, can you run you eyes over my karma.conf.js in https://github.com/jimisdrpc/basic-vanilla-webcomponent/blob/master/karma.conf.js and see if I am missing some extra config in order to make such library available during tests?

Comment: did you try ./node_modules/@open ... ?

Comment: Well, it doesn't make sense since it will look for node_modules folder inside my test folder. Any way I tried and this is the rresult:    2019 18:23:10.877:INFO [launcher]: Launching browsers Chrome with concurrency unlimited
22 07 2019 18:23:10.882:INFO [launcher]: Starting browser Chrome
22 07 2019 18:23:15.034:INFO [Chrome 75.0.3770 (Windows 10.0.0)]: Connected on socket 4LhPZuHv0flboGA-AAAA with id 94680530
22 07 2019 18:23:15.347:WARN [web-server]: 404: /base/test/@open-wc/testing

Chrome 75.0.3770 (Windows 10.0.0): Executed 0 of 0 ERROR (0.003 secs / 0 secs)

Comment: by adding the whole path ( import { html, fixture, expect } from "C:/_d/WSs/basic-vanilla-webcomponent/node_modules/@open-wc/testing"; ) I got different error but it doesn't mean much. I will edited my question adding the new error